# How to discover what a Postgresql table's usage is?

Tags: postgresql, dictionary, catalog

Our team is working on a Postgresql database with lots of tables and views, without any referential constraints. The project is undocumented and there appears to be a great number of unused/temporary/duplicate tables/views dirtying the schema.

We need to discover what database objects have real value and are actually used and accessed.
My inital thoughts were to query the Catalog/'data-dictionary'.

Is it possible to query the Postgresql Catalog to find an object's last query time.

Any thoughts, alternative approaches and or tools ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Statistics Collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the last query time but you can adjust your postgresql.conf to log all SQL:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

That will at least give you an idea of current activity.

Answer (score 1):

Reset the statistics, **[pg_stat_reset()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCS-TABLE)**, and then check the pg catalog tables like **[pg_stat_user_tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE)** and such to see where activity looks like its showing up.